# flink elasticsearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

I used the following code to connect Flink to ElasticSearch. But when running with Flink, a lot of errors are displayed.The program first enters the data from a port and then reads each line in the command line according to the program written. It then displays the number of words. The main problem is when connecting to a elasticsearch that unfortunately gives error when connecting. Are these errors? What classes do you need to connect Minimal Flink to Elastic Search?

```
public class Elastic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


       // the port to connect to
       final int port;
       try {
           final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
           port = params.getInt("port");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("No port specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount --port <port>'");
           return;
         }

        // get the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

       // get input data by connecting to the socket
       DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port, "\n");

      // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
       DataStream<WordWithCount> windowCounts = text
            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                    for (String word : value.split("\\s")) {
                        out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
                    }
                }
            })
            .keyBy("word")
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
            .reduce(new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
                @Override
                public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
                    return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
                }
            });

    // print the results with a single thread, rather than in parallel
    windowCounts.print().setParallelism(1);
    text.print().setParallelism(1);

    env.execute("Socket Window WordCount");



    List<HttpHost> httpHosts = new ArrayList<HttpHost>();
    httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 9200, "http"));
    httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("10.2.3.1", 9200, "http"));
    httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("my-ip",9200,"http"));


    ElasticsearchSink.Builder<String> esSinkBuilder = new ElasticsearchSink.Builder<String>(
            httpHosts,
            new ElasticsearchSinkFunction<String>() {
                public IndexRequest createIndexRequest(String element) {
                    Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    json.put("data", element);

                    return Requests.indexRequest()
                            .index("iran")
                            .type("int")
                            .source(json);
                }

                @Override
                public void process(String element, RuntimeContext ctx, RequestIndexer indexer) {
                    indexer.add(createIndexRequest(element));
                }
            }
    );

    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxActions(1);

    final Header[] defaultHeaders = new Header[]{new BasicHeader("header", "value")};

    esSinkBuilder.setRestClientFactory(new RestClientFactory() {
        @Override
        public void configureRestClientBuilder(RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder) {
            restClientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders)
                    .setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(10000)
                    .setPathPrefix("a")
                    .setRequestConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(RequestConfig.Builder builder) {
                            return builder.setSocketTimeout(10000);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    text.addSink(esSinkBuilder.build());


}

// Data type for words with count
public static class WordWithCount {

    public String word;
    public long count;

    public WordWithCount() {
    }

    public WordWithCount(String word, long count) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word + " : " + count;
    }
}
}
```

my elasticsearch version: 7.5.0
my flink version: 1.8.3

my error:

```
sudo /etc/flink-1.8.3/bin/flink run -c org.apache.flink.Elastic /root/FlinkElastic-1.0.jar --port 9000

------------------------------------------------------------
The program finished with the following exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[]) method from the class 
org.apache.flink.Elastic: 
org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:527)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:246)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:521)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:120)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 13 more
```

my pom:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
<artifactId>FlinkElastic</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>6</source>
                <target>6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: The phrase "rubber tire" seems out of place.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Reread your question. In the first paragraph you talk about connecting to a rubber tire.

Comment: I'm really ashamed of you. The word is misspelled. The main word is the elasticsearch. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the Flink Elastic Connector code here. I have used the following dependencies and versions mentioned below.

- Flink: 1.10.0
- ElasticSearch: 7.6.2
- flink-connector-elasticsearch7
- Scala: 2.12.11
- SBT: 1.2.8
- Java: 11.0.4

**Point to be noted here:**

- Since ElasticSearch 6.x onwards they started full support of the REST elastic client. And till Elastic5.x they were using Transport elastic client.

> ***1. Flink DataStream***

```scala
val inputStream: DataStream[(String, String)] = ...

ESSinkService.sinkToES(inputStream, index)
```

> ***2. ElastiSearchSink Function***

```scala
package demo.elastic

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RuntimeContext
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.{ElasticsearchSink, RestClientFactory}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.{ActionRequestFailureHandler, ElasticsearchSinkFunction, RequestIndexer}
import org.apache.http.HttpHost
import org.elasticsearch.client.{Requests, RestClientBuilder}
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType
import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequest
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink


class ESSinkService {

  val logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  val httpHosts = new java.util.ArrayList[HttpHost]
  httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"))
  httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"))

  def sinkToES(counted: DataStream[(String, String)], index: String): DataStreamSink[(String, String)] = {

    val esSinkBuilder = new ElasticsearchSink.Builder[(String, String)](
      httpHosts, new ElasticsearchSinkFunction[(String, String)] {
        def process(element: (String, String), ctx: RuntimeContext, indexer: RequestIndexer) {

          indexer.add(Requests.indexRequest
            .index(element._2 + "_" + index)
            .source(element._1, XContentType.JSON))
        }
      }
    )
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxActions(2)
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushInterval(1000L)
    esSinkBuilder.setFailureHandler(new ActionRequestFailureHandler {
      override def onFailure(actionRequest: ActionRequest, throwable: Throwable, i: Int, requestIndexer: RequestIndexer): Unit = {

        println("@@@@@@@On failure from ElasticsearchSink:-->" + throwable.getMessage)
      }
    })

    esSinkBuilder.setRestClientFactory(new RestClientFactory {
      override def configureRestClientBuilder(restClientBuilder: RestClientBuilder): Unit = {
        /*restClientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(...)
        restClientBuilder.setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(...)
        restClientBuilder.setPathPrefix(...)
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(...)*/
      }
    })

    counted.addSink(esSinkBuilder.build())
  }
}

object ESSinkService extends ESSinkService
```

**Note:** For more details click [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Flink doesn't yet support Elasticsearch 7. An ES7 connector will be released along with Flink 1.10.
2. You must include the flink/elasticsearch dependency in your project -- this error suggests you haven't included it:

> ClassNotFoundException: 
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkFunction

See [the elasticsearch docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html#elasticsearch-connector) for more info.

Your Flink application code runs in the task managers. Each task manager must be able to find all of your application's dependencies in its CLASSPATH. The connector classes are not included out-of-the-box, so you will need to either build an uber jar (i.e., a fat jar, or jar with dependencies), or copy the flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11 jar file into the lib directory of every machine in the cluster. See the [docs on connector dependencies](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/projectsetup/dependencies.html#adding-connector-and-library-dependencies) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to change my version of elasticsearch or Flink? (Given the git hub is a code for elastic 7) I added the attachment stated in the document. I updated the post and added my own pom file

Comment: You can either use what you've implemented now with ES6, or wait and upgrade to Flink 1.10 when it's released, and use that with ES7.

Comment: I put the Flick version on 1.8.1 and the Elasticsearch version on 6.2.4. I executed the command below but it didn't execute again and gave the previous errors...

sudo ./bin/flink run -c org.apache.flink.Elasticsearch /root/Elasticsearch-1.0.jar --port 9000