# RestHighLevelClient Not Found in Scala

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-flink, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to insert into ElasticSearch(ES) in a Scala Program.

In build.sbt I have added

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % "7.5.2" ,
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "7.5.2"
```

My code is

```
val client = new RestHighLevelClient( RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")))
```

While compiling I am getting errors as below

```
not found: type RestHighLevelClient
not found: value RestClient
```

Am I missing some import? My goal is to get a stream from  Flink and insert into ElasticSearch
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use Elasticsearch with Flink it's going to be easier if you use Flink's `ElasticsearchSink`, rather than working with `RestHighLevelClient` directly. However, a version of that sink for Elasticsearch 7.x is coming in Flink 1.10, which hasn't been released yet (it's coming very soon; RC1 is already out).

Using this connector requires an extra dependency, such as `flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11` (or `flink-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11`, coming with Flink 1.10).

See the [docs on using Elasticsearch with Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html).

The reason to prefer Flink's sink over using `RestHighLevelClient` yourself is that the Flink sink makes bulk requests, handles errors and retries, and it's tied in with Flink's checkpointing mechanism, so it's able to guarantee that nothing is lost if something fails.

As for your actual question, maybe you need to add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-client" % "7.5.2"
```

Comment: I saw the above URL, before posting the question here. It looked complicated, a simple example would have been good.  And going by your reply, it is not yet ready On the other hand RestHighLevelClient is simple to use

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: I tried to put the code from the above URL and tried to compile. I got error as below
identifier expected but 'type' found.
[error]               .type("my-type")
[error]                ^

Comment: Even after adding dependency, I am still getting the same error

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;`

Comment: For a more straightforward experience with a simpler API, you might prefer using the Table API and its ES connector. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#elasticsearch-connector

Comment: After adding the  two statements, compilation error disappeared
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient

But execution failed with the error message
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient

I am working with your suggestion too

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to use these dependencies separately to insert data in Elasticsearch by using Flink Streaming.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % "7.5.2" ,
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "7.5.2"
```

Just use this flink-connector-elasticsearch7 or flink-connector-elasticsearch6

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-elasticsearch7" % "1.10.0"
```

All dependencies of Elasticsearch come along with the Flink-Elastic connector. So we don't need to include them separately in `build.sbt` file.

**build.sbt file for Flink Elasticsearch**

```
name := "flink-streaming-demo"

scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

val flinkVersion = "1.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-elasticsearch7" % flinkVersion
```

For more details please go through this working Flink-Elasticsearch code which I have provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643158/7317816).

**Note:** Since Elastic 6.x onwards they started full support of the REST elastic client. And till Elastic5.x they were using Transport elastic client.